# How to configuration gradle scripts to handle multi project with root level build

Tags: java, gradle

Is this possible?

```
A (folder)
-B (independent project) 
-C (independent project)
-D (independent project) and depends on B and C
```

Note: I also need a root level gradle to build all the projects at folder A level.

This is what I got so far...

A (build.gradle) root level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

A (settings.gradle) root level

```
rootProject.name = 'A'
include "B"
include "C"
include "D"
```

The individual independent project builds are pretty straight forward. I am stuck when I try to build project D

```
dependencies {
    api project(':B')
    api project(':C')
}
```

Basically gradle expects B and C to be under D. I get it. But, how can I get it working the way it is?

**ANSWER : added the following in settings.gradle for D**

```
rootProject.name = 'D'

include 'B'
project(':B').projectDir = file('../B')

include 'C'
project(':C').projectDir = file('../C')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The project structure is completely independent from project dependencies**. You may define any valid (e.g. non-circular) dependency between any projects with their arbitrary project names and project directories.

---

> Basically gradle expects B and C to be under D.

No, Gradle does not expect that. Actually, your current setup should work without a problem. All involved (sub-)projects must be registered inside a **single** `settings.gradle` file. Whatever gets passed to `include` is just a project name and is not necessarily related to the actual location of the project. The method `include` uses a convention to infer the location of the project by translating the project name into a path, but it may be changed as shown in [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String%5B%5D)):

```
// include two projects, 'foo' and 'foo:bar'
// directories are inferred by replacing ':' with '/'
include 'foo:bar'

// include one project whose project dir does not match the logical project path
include 'baz'
project(':baz').projectDir = file('foo/baz')
```

As explained in the comment, the first example will create two projects, as `'foo:bar'` is a project path that requires a project called `foo` to exist. You may also use `includeFlat` to create projects with a default path that starts in the parent directory of your root directory (which is the project directory of your root project).